# How to remove empty space on ido-find-file's completions minibuffer window

Tags: minibuffer, ido

When I use `ido-find-file` and press `TAB` I see the found filenames in a half windows size. Instead could it be compact, where can emtpy space removed?

Ex:
[image]

---

minimal.el:

```
(ido-mode 1)
(require 'consult)
(require 'vertico)
(vertico-mode)
```

*Please note* that I am not able to use `icicles` due to consult does not properly work when I enable `ivy-mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE] The issue is reported to be fixed in [Emacs 29](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/4cb31b19353d3d1f8629d7c7b55aff2445efc02a) trunk.

I had this question myself and your post had stimulated me to finally research how to do it.

Here's the *current* solution (or rather a *fix*, because this behavior of the *Ido Completions* buffer *looks like* a bug to me) tested on `Emacs 28.0.50`:

```
(customize-set-variable
 'display-buffer-alist
   '(("\\*Ido Completions\\*"
      (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-at-bottom)
      (window-height . fit-window-to-buffer))))
```

Additionally, try out `'one-column` output:

```
(setq completions-format 'one-column) ; or 'vertical / 'horizontal
```

Documentation on [display-buffer-alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Window-Choice).

P.S.
I probably should have also mentioned that typing `C-f` (after `C-x C-f` calling `ido-find-file`) allows to fallback to non-ido `find-file` with the currently more standard completions buffer behavior. `C-h f ido-magic-forward-char` lists all `C-f` initiated "magic actions".

Comment: Thanks! Smal questions, first `TAB` shows all column format I believe than on the second TAB the list becomes wider and its heifght decreases. Would it be possible to show in same height if multiple `TAB`s pressed?

Comment: Note that \*Completions\* buffer acts the same way (at least in my setup with fido-mode, tested with `M-x prev RET`). The end of the documentation `C-h f fit-window-to-buffer` might be addressing this issue. Though I didn't investigate thoroughly (yet).

Comment: Actually, after more research, it looks like a bug in `ido` again to me. The list of completions gets "re-drawn" on the second TAB hit. There'e no such issue with `emacs -Q` completions. There's a chance I'll dig deeper (I already did but not enough to find the fix). I'll let you know if I have a solution/fix for that.

Comment: Thank you :-) `icicles` handles it well but I was not able to use it along with `consult`

Comment: FYI, I filed these issues as [a bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=50671) several days ago.